# [Resolved] Communication between Kinetic and Indigo only working one-way

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to set a Master-Slave using my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04 w/ ROS Kinetic) as master and an UDOO Quad (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.14.56-udooqdl-02044-gddaad11 armv7l) w/ ROS Indigo ARM) as a client and a router (TP-LINK TL-WR841N V7) to set the network for both devices.

I've already done all the steps given [here](https://github.com/ut-ims-robotics/tutorials/wiki/Running-ROS-over-multiple-computers), where I set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the IP on my PC. So far I can see topics via `rostopic list` either on my PC or via ssh on the UDOO.

The problem I have is that when I try a simple publisher node like `rostopic pub \testing std_msgs\String hello`, I can only get the message using `rostopic echo \testing` when I do it on the machine I am publishing from (even through ssh), I get nothing if I do it on the other machine.

I've read other questions like [#q9915](https://answers.ros.org/question/9915/ros-mutiple-machine/) and [#q76279](https://answers.ros.org/question/76279/different-ros-versions-on-multiple-machines/). I've tried to disable the firewall, set the `ROS_HOSTNAME`, but neither of those solutions worked for me.

My intuition says to me that it should not be a problem with the messages between the machines since I am only sending a String which is one of the basic std_msgs.

Could it be a networking problem?
Could it be a compatibility problem since I am running Kinetic on one device and Indigo on the other?

Any help will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313413/%5Bresolved%5D-communication-between-kinetic-and-indigo-only-working-one-way/) by [manu-diaz-zapata](https://answers.ros.org/users/39614/manu-diaz-zapata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-01-22**:
This sounds like a networking issue. I did a talk about network troubleshooting at ROSCon a few years back: https://vimeo.com/67806888 .

**Comment by [manu-diaz-zapata](https://answers.ros.org/users/39614/manu-diaz-zapata/) on 2019-01-22**:
If I have time I'll look into that dnsmasq setup for my lab, because it sounds like I will save us some hassle. I've already added on both machines the IP of the other on `\etc\hosts`. And the weird thing is that before I went home, I managed to listen from my PC to something published in the UDOO.

**Comment by [manu-diaz-zapata](https://answers.ros.org/users/39614/manu-diaz-zapata/) on 2019-01-22**:
I think I'll try the `rosnode info` and see what debugging I can do from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found the reason why it wasn't working. Just needed to give the IP of my PC on the WLAN to the `ROS_IP` environment variable on my PC. Once I disabled the firewall, everything worked as expected.

---

Originally posted by [manu-diaz-zapata](https://answers.ros.org/users/39614/manu-diaz-zapata/) with karma: 16 on 2019-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-01-24**:
I'm glad that you found the solution. I've accepted your answer. Now that you have enough karma, you should be able accept your own answer in the future.